# Why MinMaxScaler applied only to certain columns doesn't normalize my dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-mining, data-analysis

I need to normalize the columns in my dataset, avoiding to normalize certain columns already having small values and a standard deviation below 1. All the columns that I want to normalized are store in the **columns_to_normalize** list. Performing the following code still doesn't help in the normalization process:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from pandas import DataFrame
# create scaler
minmax_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('minmax', MinMaxScaler())])

# perform normalization on the dataset, avoiding ordinal columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        remainder='passthrough', 
        transformers=[
            ('mm', minmax_transformer , columns_to_normalize)
        ])

# fit and transform model on data
df_norm_values = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

# convert the array back to a dataframe
df_norm = DataFrame(df_norm_values)

# set columns' names
column_names = list(df.columns)
df_norm.columns = column_names
# normalized input variable's summarry
df_norm.describe()
```

[image]
For istance the last 2 columns aren't fully normalized, since the minimum values are 0.00 and 1.00 and the maximum 3.00 and 4.00) and I don't understand why my code doesn't succeed in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaler is working alright, but the `ColumnTransformer` is changing the order of columns :

From the [ColumnTransformer's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) :

> The order of the columns in the transformed feature matrix follows the
> order of how the columns are specified in the transformers list.
> Columns of the original feature matrix that are not specified are
> dropped from the resulting transformed feature matrix, unless
> specified in the passthrough keyword. Those columns specified with
> passthrough are added at the right to the output of the transformers.

Here is a quick fix :

```
minmax_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('minmax', MinMaxScaler())])

# perform normalization on the dataset, avoiding ordinal columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        remainder='passthrough', 
        transformers=[
            ('mm', minmax_transformer , columns_to_normalize)
        ])

# fit and transform model on data
df_norm_values = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

# convert the array back to a dataframe
df_norm = DataFrame(df_norm_values)

# set columns' names
passthrough_cols = list(df.columns)
for col in columns_to_normalize: # remove cols that will be scaled
    passthrough_cols.remove(col)

column_names = columns_to_normalize
column_names.extend(passthrough_cols) # stack columns names

df_norm.columns = column_names
# normalized input variable's summarry
df_norm.describe()
```